# How to create an app that gets code from TFS and compiles it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, compilation

I have to create a simple console/winform app that receives a parameter, plants it into other code and compiles it.

The change inside the code itself is simple, just changing the value of a variable.

Edit: I want to add that the program i want to compile is in TFS and i need to get the latest code, change a variable and then compile.

The question is: how can i manage to get the program from TFS without having VS installed? I mean how can the person that will use my app will access it?

I read some tutorials but they all mention that there has to be a workspace in order for it to work. The person who'll use it probably won't have VS and workspace.

Thanks

Comment: There are plenety of duplicates... Not sure which one you like the most. Please search and decide - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+compile+programmatically

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I edited my question and it's more specific now. Thanks for the link, it helped me to start.

Comment: Why not use one of the dozens of continuous integration tools already on the market? What you're describing sounds like a reinvention of the wheel in a big way.

Comment: As @DanielMann pointed out what you've described is done many times already... On other hand you may be looking for way more complicated solution for just configuring application (i.e. via app.config). You may research alternative approaches to what you *actually* trying to achieve (possibly asking new clarifying questions of SO after you done with research)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can build your C# app using the MSBuild.exe command line tool.
In the past I used batch to do so, but you can use the C# to do as well.

You can read about [MSBuild tool Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)